# How to convert an array of pixels to jpg or png?

Tags: vhdl, imageprocessing

I am doing image processing project in VHDL. And as output am getting array of pixels (32 bit each). I want test this output data visually, for that it must be converted to image either png or jpg or bmp. How can I do that?

Edit:  Or if am getting same data in four different files like alpha, red, green and blue in a.txt, r.txt, g.txt and  b.txt respectively. Does this make it easier to get the image ?

Comment: How do you collect the data to your computer? Do you have Matlab?

Comment: I collected all data in txt file and I have Matlab in my PC

Comment: You can find something called sim_bmppack if you search. Maybe you can unroll things from there. I have seen it used together with some tcl-hooks or similar, so the image is loaded/displayed during simulation.

Comment: This is really off topic.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, how is this question off topic? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL

Comment: If not off topic it's too broad.

Comment: Do the pixels have alpha values?

Comment: If you can use Visual C++ or other C++ implementation, I would recommend you the CxImage library http://sourceforge.net/projects/cximage/ It is easy to work with it and very functional http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1300/CxImage Documentation is on site http://www.xdp.it/cximage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There, probably, many ways to do this, but if you can use Matlab, this should not be too difficult. It's been a long time I used it, so I do not remember the details, but the general approach is as follows:

First, you need to read out the values from the .txt file into your workspace. Create four equal size matrices and load each of them with alpha, red, blue, greed data respectively. You will have to write a small function to copy data from the txt matrix. Can not tell you how, because I do not know how the data is stored in the .txt file.

There are different ways to display images in Matlab. Check out the help file on how to create a RGB image from its components. There is a built in function that will do it for you (concatenation). So, when you have separate R G B matrices/channels (of equal size), you can concatenate them across the third dimension:

```
  im = cat(3,R,G,B);
```

Then you can use these functions (and other) to display the image:

```
  imshow(im)
  imagesc(im)
```

I do not know how the alpha channel applies to the RGB image. Read some docs on it. Maybe you do not need it.

In any case, you can easily edit the data in the matrices so it can be accepted for image creation.

Once you have the channels you can create and save the image in a variety of common image formats that are supported by Matlab, including .jpg and .png.

Answer (score 3):

What about Open cores [jpg encoder](http://opencores.org/project,mkjpeg)?

Comment: Is it software or online tool. I saw one download link in the page that you showed. 1st step download and install software ?

Comment: @tollin, it's just VHDL code but it's in a tar.gz so if you're running Windows you probably want an archive manager like WinRAR to extract it. You need to sign up at Open Cores to download but I've been signed up for ages and they don't send any junk e-mail.

Comment: @PeterJ like you said. I registered, downloaded, Extracted. Now I have .tar_2 file. I opened with notepad++ got very large vhdl code with some documents.

Comment: @PeterJ What is next?  Can I compile that doc in Quartus?

Answer (score 2):

Write out image data in ascii PPM format is easy:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PPM_example
A lot of image viewer understand that format, for example Irfanview.

There's also a more complex format supporting 32bit with alpha channel:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PAM_graphics_format

So you at least have to create the right header in front of your data.
The netpbm package delivers some command line conversion tools:
pamtotiff, pamtopnm, pamtojpeg2k,...

I often used that ppm format for testbenches in the past...

Comment: I cannot change the format. In the 32 bit data that am getting as my result first 8 bit is alpha value followed by red, green and blue.

Comment: @tollin Changing the format is not a problem. You just need to multiply each 8-bit channel by 4 (or shift by 2).  It will not change the quality of the image, but you will have a 32-bit values, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Insert VHDL code in your testbench to write the raw frame to a file.  Then use a jpeg encoder/compressor to generate the jpg, and finally open it with your favorite image viewer.

I can vouch for this (aptly named) [jpeg-compressor](https://code.google.com/p/jpeg-compressor/).

Using it couldn't be easier:

```
// Writes JPEG image to a file. 
// num_channels must be 1 (Y), 3 (RGB), or 4 (RGBA), image pitch must be width*num_channels.
bool compress_image_to_jpeg_file(const char *pFilename, 
                                 int width, int height, 
                                 int num_channels, 
                                 const uint8 *pImage_data, 
                                 const params &comp_params = params());
```

You just need to write a tiny C++ program that calls this function.  Some years ago I implemented it on Nios II to save (and later load) live video snapshots, and it worked well.  Slow, yes, but sure.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to interpret a raw array of pixel data as a image.  You may be able to use my INF image file mechanism for that.  You create a text file that contains commands to the INF reader to explain where the pixel data is in the raw array.

Various image manipulation utilities, which include the INF file driver, should be included in my Full Runtime release at http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm.  After you install that, documentation files will be in the DOC directory within wherever you installed the software to.  In particularly, look at the INF doc file to see if this will do what you want.

The image manipulation programs are generally named IMAGE_xxx, with corresponding doc files in the DOC directory.  If you set up the INF file right, then IMAGE_COPY will be able to convert your pixel data to a JPG file, or a number of other file formats.  The supported file formats are listed in the IMAGE_TYPES doc file.  You could also use IMAGE_DISP or IMAGE_EDIT to see the image directly without it first being converted to a standard file format.